# Finding max path in a maze skipping 2 cells

Tags: c++, c, recursion, maze

[image]

Finding max path from (0,0) to (5,7) skips cells 1,5 and 2,5. Can anyone explain why? I get 3 different paths, but not the max path which the question needs.

```
int visited[10][10];
int max_len=0;
void max_path(int a[][10],int x,int y,int x1,int y1,int value=0){
    if(x==x1 && y==y1){
        if(max_len<value)
            max_len=value;
    }

    else{
        if(x+1<10 && !visited[x+1][y] && a[x+1][y]!=0){
            visited[x][y]=1;
            max_path(a,x+1,y,x1,y1,value+1);
            visited[x][y]=0;
        }

        if(y+1<10 && !visited[x][y+1] && a[x][y+1]!=0){
            visited[x][y]=1;
            max_path(a,x,y+1,x1,y1,value+1);
            visited[x][y]=0;
        }

        if(y-1>=0 && !visited[x][y-1] && a[x][y-1]!=0){
            visited[x][y]=1;
            max_path(a,x,y-1,x1,y1,value+1);
            visited[x][y]=0;
        }

        if(x-1>=0 && !visited[x-1][y] && a[x-1][y]!=0){
            visited[x][y]=1;
            max_path(a,x-1,y,x1,y1,value+1);
            visited[x-1][y]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and [what is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: `visited[x-1][y]=0;` -> The `x-1` looks off?

Comment: You're recursively trying different paths, but using a global "visited" flag.

Answer (score 1):

You always change the value of visited[x][y] to 1 then after the recursive call change it back to 0, except at the last 'if' where you set visited[x-1][y] to 0 leaving the visited[x][y] to 1. You are not able to return more in recursion if you can step in the direction of the left since it will always stay visited.